# Wouldn't Julie go to jail as well?

Tags: plot-explanation, jawbreaker

In the 1999 film Jawbreaker wouldn't Julie have also gone to jail right along with Courtney and Marcie?

Even if she and Zach had found the photo in the parking lot, it still would have been her word against Courtney's. So, I don't get what they thought finding it would solve.

The recording of Courntey admitting to the crime doesn't omit Julie from guilt either. She'd still be in trouble.